# How to authenticate user and admin at the same time in a django project

Tags: python, django, authentication, admin

I am new to `django`. My web application in `django` using `auth functions` to authenticate users with a custom made admin panel. **Is it possible to authenticate user and admin at the same time from a browser?**(without using incognito window)